# Form filling automation: Why is send_keys filling in more than one field automatically?

Tags: python, forms, selenium, automation

I'm writing the following using Python and Selenium in Windows, with the objective of filling in two fields with the current date and a specified time for each field:

```
#Defines and inputs date and time into End Time field 
x = datetime.datetime.now()
endtime = x.strftime("%m/%d/%Y" " 8:30 AM")
endtime_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_endDt"]')
endtime_field.send_keys([endtime])

#Defines and inputs date and time into Start Time field 
starttime = x.strftime("%m/%d/%Y" " 8:28 AM")
starttime_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_startDt"]')
starttime_field.send_keys([starttime])
```

When I run the file in Chromebrowser, the `endtime_field` is filled correctly, but `starttime_field` is automatically filled with the entries of both endtime and starttime, without a space, ie:

04/27/2020 8:30 AM04/27/2020 8:28 AM

It seems that endtime_field.send_keys is being run automatically in the second field even though it has a different XPath. I note there's no space after the AM from `endtime` and before the 04 from `starttime`.

I've tried moving from `endtime_field` to `starttime_field` using `Keys.TAB` and also performing `starttime_field.clear()` before filling it in, but they both don't work.

Here's what the `starttime_field` element looks like using browser Inspect:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$startDt" type="text" id="MainContent_startDt" class="form-control">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any loop or conditioning  statement  on top on this code.Did you check how application  behaves without  automation when u select  same values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send_keys` method works similar to manual typing and it doesn't take into account the current focus or context of selection.
In your case, it seems like the focus is going to another control before flushing/writing all the characters in one control.

From python selenium docs:

```
send_keys(*keys_to_send)
Sends keys to current focused element.
Args:   
keys_to_send: The keys to send. Modifier keys constants can be found in the ‘Keys’ class.

send_keys_to_element(element, *keys_to_send)
Sends keys to an element.
Args:   
element: The element to send keys.
keys_to_send: The keys to send. Modifier keys constants can be found in the ‘Keys’ class.
```

Comment: Yes it seems that the first send_keys hasn’t been put to a stop of sorts. Could you elaborate on how one might end the first control? Thanks

Comment: You can use starttime_field.click() before send_keys of the last line.

Comment: Great it worked -- thanks! Just for my learning -- this click finishes 'endtime_field.send_keys([endtime])' right? Going by this logic, would I need to do a fresh 'click()' some where before the next step?

Comment: Yes, you need to move your current focus by using click() if you are using **send_keys(*keys_to_send)** method.